# How can I make Google Play Services appear in the Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

Recently after an OTA update I got the "Can't run this unless you update Google Play Services" message (due to the version in the image being older than the one running on the previous image).

Hitting the notification took me to the "Google Play Services" app in the Play Store, and I could see the progress as it was downloaded, as well as see reviews and a change-list (like normal apps).

That was *incredibly* handy.  However searching the play store or looking at "My Apps" doesn't find "Google Play Services", so I can't get back there.

Does anyone know if there is a configuration option that allows you to find and view Google Play Services in the Play Store normally.  There are a number of times where this would be really handy...

Comment: It's insane to me that the only way to get to it is by Googling for it and then bring it up that way. Why remove it from the Play Store listings if it's such an important component to the Android Operating System.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go - [Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)
Right click on above-mentioned link to copy the link or left click to head over to app page on Play Store.

Comment: Hmm,... Link open's Chrome (not my default browser) then ends up on "We're sorry the requested URL was not found on this server"

Comment: R u using desktop browser? Actually the link opens in Google Play by default or any default browser in android.

Comment: Nope - Nexus 5 - Android 5.0.2.

Comment: Yeah you are right. The link doesn't seem to work in browser. You definitely need Google Play to open the link.

Comment: Ok - you've essentially given me the answer:  search for "Google Play Services" in Google (or in your browser).  Visit the link which _may_ take you to the Web play-store entry for it, then Launch the link in an app (ie as an intent - in Firefox hit the "android" in the address bar).

Comment: Haven't tried it in Chrome - an old phone with 4.1 (and no chrome) fails to launch the link from "Android Browser".  So there's something hit-and-miss about it,...

Comment: Ok - the issue seems to be the URL you typed is mashed-up - it has a repetition.  I tried fixing the URL, but not enough rep so it is "awaiting peer review"

Comment: Link updated. You can mark this as an answer if the problem is solved.

Comment: It is weird that your can't get to the google play services app with a google store search, I always got to it from links on android sites. I needed a link to it for my game, as most of my players are foreign and didn't download my app from google play in the first place, so they can't use learderboards, etc. I'm hoping they can successfully manually download and use it.